Why I can't install Django channels?
My OS is ubuntu 24.04. I am trying to create a chat application in Django. For that I need django channels and try to install them with pip install channels command. After executing this command I get this error:
pip install channels
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.


I just want to install with pip the django channels to use it in chat application.

This question is similar to: pip install -r requirements.txt is failing: "This environment is externally managed". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How do I solve "error: externally-managed-environment" every time I use pip 3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should use virtual env as Ubuntu prevent users from installing Python packages directly in system.
So simply create virtual env:
sudo apt install python3-venv
cd /path/to/yourproject
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

And install it into your virtualenv:
pip install channels

